# PhantomJS not found on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, phantomjs, systemd

I'm trying to export a Bokeh plot to an image. For that, I use the method `export_png` which uses PhantomJS and Selenium underneathh. However, I got a RuntimeError

```
RuntimeError: PhantomJS is not present in PATH or BOKEH_PHANTOMJS_PATH. 
Try "conda install phantomjs" or "npm install -g phantomjs-prebuilt"
```

This behavior can be reproduced :

**Notebook**

```
import shutil
shutil.which('phantomjs') or 'not found'
# --> "not found"
```

**With IPython in the same virtualenv**

```
import shutil
shutil.which('phantomjs') or 'not found'
# --> "/home/<user>/miniconda/envs/p36/bin/phantomjs"
```

**[Edit]**

The notebook server runs as a service on Linux (Ubuntu). I think the issue come from this because when I manually launch the notebook server, `phantomJS` path is well found on the notebook. Here the detailed systemd file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Jupyter Notebook
After=multi-user.target network.target

[Service]
User=<myuser>
Group=<mygroup>
EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment
Type=idle
Restart=always
RestartSec=3
ExecStart=/home/<user>/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/bin/jupyter-notebook --no-browser --notebook-dir="/home/<user>/src"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**[Solution]**

The problem is more a systemd issue than a Python one: `$PATH` environment variable used is the one of the root user, not the one of the specified user. I did not found any clear way to load the `.bashrc` file before running the script of the service. The solution was then to use an environment file wherein I declared the `$PATH` variable the same way it is done in the `.bashrc` file. Everything works like a sharm after that.

Answer (score 1):

### There is no (and never will be any) built-in way to load `~/.bashrc` of a specified user prior to starting a process in systemd.

*[Nit: if you are setting an environment variable in your dotfiles, do it in `~/.bash_profile`, not `~/.bashrc`. The former is sourced by all login shells (rougly one time per login), the latter is sourced by every interactive shell (and is not sourced by the login shells, so your DE's root processes won't get these variables).]*

systemd is not a bash interpreter. `~/.bashrc` may contain arbitrary bash code, not just environment variable assignments, therefore there is no way for systemd to implement such functionality.

So, if you need to run arbitrary shell code, simply do it explicitly:

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '...'
```

Comment: Ubuntu uses ~/.profile instead of ~/.bash_profile [https://askubuntu.com/a/510723/872782]

Comment: @GuillaumeA I don't claim familiarity with Ubuntu. If so, please suggest an edit.

Comment: I'm not a linux expert either and your answer is helpful by the way.